# How does Xcode know if it needs to do a pod install when changing a branch?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cocoapods

Suddenly a question came to mind.
When I change branch and it has some pod changes, then Xcode fails the build shows an error message telling you to install the pod (and we all know this).

The question is how does Xcode know this?
I don't think Xcode is looking at the hash of Podfile.lock, is there any other way for Xcode to know pod changes?

Answer (score 2):

It's not purely Xcode.

The error shown is `error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.`, right? It's a message hardcoded into a Shell script that CocoaPods adds to Build Phases of your Xcode workspace:

```sh
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
# ...
```

The script is typically added before the Compile Sources step.